# How to configure app to run in elevated mode from Standard User Account?

Tags: windows-8.1, uac

How to configure my c# app to run in elevated mode from Standard User Account?

Generally i would like to add permission for a program to run in elevated mode
under standard user account without popping up the window:

"Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes to this computer?" And The administrator password is required...

Answer (score 0):

The [task scheduler workaround](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=135472) not possible with a standard user account because it doesn't have an admin token.

You must first activate the hidden admin account next use the `RunAs` command with the `/savecred` parameter and enter the admin password at least 1 time. Next time Windows reads the encrypted password and runs the tool as admin.

```
runas /user:ComputerName\Administrator /savecred "C:\Path\Program.exe"
```

Comment: net user admins /active:yes results in Access Denied (5) - even in elevated mode. Furthermore,  I get: runas 740 the requested operation requires elevation ...