# How to Configure own's .NET application to run under Standard User Account without administrative level with UAC enabled?

Tags: windows, windows-8, .net-framework

My question relates to another similar:

[How to configure app to run in elevated mode from Standard User Account?](https://superuser.com/questions/760193/how-to-configure-app-to-run-in-elevated-mode-from-standard-user-account/760331)

Generally I am curious:

What should I do to configure my .NET the application to run under Standard User Account 
without needed elevated mode? (To get rid of the window: Do you want to allow the following program from an unknown publisher to make changes to this computer.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean what code patterns? Or an existing .exe you compiled and want to bypass UAC prompts?

Comment: It works the other way around: If you don’t explicitly specify the need for elevated privileges in an application’s manifest, it won’t run elevated without manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your query correctly, you would like your application to be able to perform privileged operations without UAC prompts.

in order to do that, MS expects you to architect your application as two separate components, a service running in system-space, and a client application in user-space. that way the service is running in an elevated state, and is started by an high integrity process, but the client connecting to it need not do so.

Of course, installing, registering, and starting a service requires admin, but once installed and rebooted, any user with access to the application should be able to invoke the privledged service component without additional privldges for the interactive user.